# Create xml file by using sql trigger or LINQ to Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities

I want to trace the database when user is insert update or delete any record.I noe I can trace database by create sql trigger.
I actually want to store those record changes in xml file, then sql trigger will save xml file to database

Is it possible to make it?Or using other way? For eg : LINQ to Entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should search for this first.
You can use `FOR XML` or `xp_cmdshell`.
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803911/generating-xml-file-from-sql-server-2008) is like you wanna do.

Thanks.