# Generated KML file from SQL query save to local drive

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, kml

My SQL Query generates a XML output:

```
         select 'TEST.kml' as name,
                 (select 'TEST' as name, (
                 select ( 
                       select top 10 issue as name,
                         null as description,
                         null as 'Point/coordinates',
                         (
                              select 
                                        null as altitudeMode,
                                        Coordinates as 'coordinates'
                              for xml path('Polygon'), type)
                 from Mapping for xml path('Placemark'), type))
                     for xml path ('Line') , type)
                 for xml path ('Doc'), root('kml'))
```

I want to save the output of the query as .XML file on to local drive.Please advise.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: [Generating XML file from SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1803911/243373).

Comment: It's missing some context. What trigger this query? A web app which outputs to the user a download? A scheduled job which stores a single queried parameter output to the FS? Or a schedeled job that traverses a series of parameters and for each one grasps an output file? Or other that traverses a series of parameters generating a single file?

Answer (score 5):

Not the most elegant way but it is possible to use `bulk copy program` and  `xp_cmdshell` to do this. Few things first, `xp_cmdshell` is **blocked** by default by SQL Server as part of the **security configuration** so you will need to enable that first and `BCP` requires you to have access to the directory that you want to create the file.

To enable `xp_cmdshell` you'll need run `sp_configure` and `RECONFIGURE`, use this:

```sql
EXEC sp_configure'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Then you can run the following:

```sql
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM [Database].dbo.[Table] FOR XML AUTO,
ELEMENTS" queryout "C:\test.xml" -c -T'
```

Just add your query into it and make sure you add `[]` around your table names.

The **Microsoft Documents** for xp_cmdshell are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql) and bcp can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility)

Answer (score 3):

Using `bcp` is definite choice especially when working with large data sets. Alternatively, you can try using `SQL Management Studio` - `Export Data`.

1. Open the interface - `Right Click` on database name, then `Tasks`, then `Export Data`
2. The menu is opened. Click `Next`

   [image]
3. Then choose `SQL Server Native Client`, sql server, database name and authentication method:

   [image]
4. Then where to save the data:

   [image]
5. Then how we are getting the data (in your case SQL query):

   [image]
6. Past the query:

   [image]
7. Then we have some settings, click `finish`.

   [image]

Answer (score 3):

To save the results of a remote query to a local file, you could use a Powershell script like this example:

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI")
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(@("
    select 'TEST.kml' as name,
                 (select 'TEST' as name, (
                 select ( 
                       select top 10 issue as name,
                         null as description,
                         null as 'Point/coordinates',
                         (
                              select 
                                        null as altitudeMode,
                                        Coordinates as 'coordinates'
                              for xml path('Polygon'), type)
                 from Mapping for xml path('Placemark'), type))
                     for xml path ('Line') , type)
                 for xml path ('Doc'), root('kml');"), $connection);
$connection.Open();
$command.ExecuteScalar() | Out-File -FilePath "C:\KmlFiles\YourFile.kml";
$connection.Close();
```

The script can be executed from a command prompt by saving the script to a file with a ".ps1" extension and using a command like:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\PowershellScripts\ExampleExport.ps1"
```

This command can be scheduled using a Windows Task Scheduler task to automate the export. Alternatively, schedule using a SQL Server agent job with a Powershell or CmdExec step.

Comment: hi how do we execute this script?

Comment: @user1046415, I added methods to my answer.